# Append and replace the contents of one map to another map?

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map, unordered

So I know `map1.insert(map2.begin(), map2.end());` will insert all elements of `map2` into `map1`.

But there can be some elements of `map2` which already exist in `map1`. These elements will not be updated.

```
e.g. map1 has { 3 : 4, 6 : 7 }
     map2 has { 11: 5, 6 : 0 }

     Now if I do map1.insert(map2.begin(), map2.end()), I will get
     map1 = { 3: 4, 6 : 7, 11 : 5 }

     But what I want is
     map1 = { 3: 4, 6 : 0, 11 : 5 }
```

I want to know is there any function like `map1.insert(map2.begin(), map2.end());` which forces an update of keys that already exists?

Update:
I know it can be done using: `map1[k] = v` for all key, value pairs in map2.

But is there any function like `map1.insert(map2.begin(), map2.end())` which can do this?

Comment: Step 1: for each element in map2 find in map 1
Step 2: If found No Op
Step 3: If not found insert

Comment: Seems as simple as map1[k] = v for all key, value pairs in map2.

Comment: Is there no function like ``map1.insert(map2.begin(), map2.end())'' that can do this? Otherwise yeah it can be done using map1[k] = v

Comment: Do you care about `map2`'s contents afterwards?

Comment: With C++17 support you could use [insert_or_assign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert_or_assign) with `for_each` and a lambda, but to me that's far more complicated than a simple free function.

Comment: @T.C. no i don't

Answer (score 5):

In C++17, merge then swap.

```
map2.merge(map1);
map2.swap(map1);
```

The benefit of this compared to the insertion-based variants is that it just splices the nodes; no allocation, no assignment, no construction.

Comment: Argh. I just overlooked `map::merge()` and figured out a way to do it myself via a loop over `map2.insert(move(map1.extract(it++)))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the opposite and then swap maybe.

`map2.insert(map1.begin(), map1.end());
std::swap(map1, map2);`

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename MapT>
void join_inplace(MapT& m1, MapT const& m2)
{
    for (auto p : m2)
        m1[p.first] = p.second;
}
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/8vQDoG)

EDIT

as you don't care about `map2`

```
template<typename MapT>
void join_inplace(MapT& target, MapT& other)
{
    for (auto& p : other)
        target[std::move(p.first)] = p.second;
}
```

Comment: [T.C. answer can provide better perf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731270/453271)

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't care about the state of `map2` afterwards, you may **move** its elements

```
template<typename MapT>
void join_inplace(MapT& map1, MapT &&map2)
{
  for(auto& p : map2)
    map1.insert_or_assign(std::move(p.first), std::move(p.second));
  map2.clear();
}
```

which does not require the mapped type to be default constructible (unlike solutions based on `map::operator[]`).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a C++17 solution which avoids any allocations, copies, or moves (of keys and mapped types)

```
template<typename MapT>
void join_inplace(MapT&map1, MapT&&map2)
{
  for(auto it=map1.begin(), end=map1.end(); it!=end;)
    map2.insert(std::move(map1.extract(it++)));
  std::swap(map1,map2);
}
```

Explanation.

1. [`map::extract(it)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract) extracts a [node](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle) whereby invaliding the iterator `it`. Therefore, we must post-increment the iterator via `map1.extract(it++)` rather than in the `for` loop as usual.
2. [`map::insert(node_type&&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) inserts the node *iff* the key is not already known.
3. Otherwise the node is destroyed
4. Finally, we must swap the maps (as per valentindavid's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44730414/1023390)).

NOTE. It was during me writing this answer that the equivalent but much simpler [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731270/1023390) of T.C. appeared. I just implemented `map::merge()` with my for loop.

Comment: Note: this does *not* work. The key should be updated if it already exist. Append and *replace*.